# Showing $k! \cdot q_k(n) \leq \binom{n-1}{k-1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $q_k(n)$ denote the number of distinct partitions of some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with exactly $k$ parts. How can I show that:
$$k! \cdot q_k(n) \leq \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

There is a related inequality that I reasoned out which was $k! \cdot p_k(n) \geq \binom{n-1}{k-1}$, where $p_k(n)$ denotes the number of partitions of $n$ with exactly $k$ parts. The way I justified this one was by recognizing
the right-hand side counts the number of ordered $k$-tuples of positive integer solutions $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k)$ satisfying
$$\sum_{i=1}^k x_i = n$$

By definition, $p_k(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ with $k$ parts, and order is not considered within a partition. By multiplying this by $k!$ we count each permutation of the $k$-sized partitions.

For some ordered $k$-tuple of positive integer solutions, there are at most $k!$ distinct $k$-tuples containing the same numbers. This only occurs when all $k$ numbers are distinct. The inequality $k! \cdot p_k(n) \geq \binom{n-1}{k-1}$ follows.

Is there some similar reasoning to reach the first inequality?

Comment: What is the difference between $q_k(n)$ and $p_k(n)$? Is it that for $q_k(n)$ we are only counting partitions where all of the parts of the partition are different? i.e. Is $q_k(n) = p_k \left( n - \frac{k(k - 1)}{2} \right)$?

Comment: That's correct. The difference is the $q_k(n)$ counts partitions where all parts are distinct, and $p_k(n)$ can include partitions with more than one of the same part. Yes to that equality as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use essentially the same argument as in your proof for the related inequality. Each partition with distinct parts corresponds to exactly $k!$ distinct compositions of the number $n$ with $k$ parts. So there are at least $k! q_k(n)$ compositions of $n$ with $k$ parts, and as in your proof for the related inequality, we know that the number of compositions of $n$ with $k$ parts is $$ \binom{n - 1}{k - 1}. $$

i.e. If $x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_k$ is such that $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_k = n$, so that $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k)$ is one of the partitions counted by $q_k(n)$, then this corresponds to $k!$ solutions to
$$
  y_1 + y_2 + \dots + y_k = n
$$
because we can take $y_i = x_{\sigma(i)}$ where $\sigma$ is some permutation of $\{1, 2, \dots, k\}$, and there are $k!$ such permutations. This implies that there are at least $k! q_k(n)$ solutions to
$$
  y_1 + y_2 + \dots + y_k = n
$$
but we know that there are exactly
$$ \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} $$
solutions.

Comment: Ok I see, what is happening is that $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ includes all the permutations of $q_k(n)$ as well as those that have $k$ parts where some of the parts are repeated.